# Bind9 as non-recursive public DNS forwarder for AD

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, active-directory, bind

We use Active Directory. We have two local networks in domain, one in our building and one on Amazon. We are using two domain controllers on each local network. All 4 of them are synchronized over VPN.

Our goal was to setup Bind9 server and use it as non-recursive public DNS forwarder for our domain. The two DC is recursive and private to prevent DNS amplification attacks.
A guy (who was there before me) was able to do it on our local network a long time ago.

Now we wanted to do the same for our local network on Amazon. I used the same configuration with modification of network range etc. But I was not able to make it work. Recursion is enabled on DCs (At least when I am trying to make it work, other times, I am turning it off because of security). I also tried to turn off the firewall on the Bind9 server. Nothing has changed.

I am not sure, where the problem is. Since we have it working on other local network I think that the problem is not in Bind9 configuration. I think the problem is in the local network or on our DC configuration. Or maybe just on the Linux system configuration?

Can anyone point me to right direction what to check/setup?

Local working setup - Bind9 installed on Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Amazon not working setup - Bind9 installed on Ubuntu 20.04 lts

Log from service on working network

```
named[7715]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 3
named[7715]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[7715]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[7715]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
named[7715]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[7715]: zone domain.com/IN: loaded serial 875311
named[7715]: all zones loaded
named[7715]: running
named[7715]: zone domain.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 875311)
```

Log from service from amazon network

```
named[1292]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 18
named[1292]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[1292]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[1292]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
named[1292]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
named[1292]: all zones loaded
named[1292]: running
....  
named[1292]: zone domain.com/IN: Transfer started.
named[1292]: transfer of 'domain.com/IN' from 10.0.0.15#53: connected using 10.0.0.150#37881
named[1292]: transfer of 'domain.com/IN' from 10.0.0.15#53: failed while receiving responses: REFUSED
named[1292]: transfer of 'domain.com/IN' from 10.0.0.15#53: Transfer status: REFUSED
named[1292]: transfer of 'domain.com/IN' from 10.0.0.15#53: Transfer completed: 0 messages, 0 records, 0 bytes, 0.001 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

named.conf.local

```
zone "domain.com" IN {
    type slave;
    file "fwd.domain.com";
    masters { 10.0.0.15; 10.0.0.190; };
};

zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type slave;
    file "rev.domain.com"; 
    masters { 10.0.0.15; 10.0.0.190; };
};
```

named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        rate-limit{
                responses-per-second 5;
        };
        allow-query {any;};
        allow-transfer {none;};
        recursion no;
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easy: I forgot to allow Zone Transfer on Windows DNS server.